# How to search an input tag value from a series of arrays

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, html

I am trying to pull information from an array that consists of a number of other arrays.

The problem I am trying to solve is I am trying to pull a number from a range located in a variety of arrays and am having trouble doing so.

Here is my JS code

I made a range() function with Javascript that lists the (start, end) of the parameters included

```
      function rangeSCORE(start, end) {
            return Array(end - start + 1).fill().map((_, idx) => start + idx)
        }


const score = document.getElementById('score').value;

const levelOneScore = rangeSCORE(486, 489);
const levelTwoScore = rangeSCORE(490, 493);
const levelThreeScore = rangeSCORE(494, 497);
const levelFourScore = rangeSCORE(498, 501);
const levelFiveScore = rangeSCORE(502, 505);
const levelSixthScore = rangeSCORE(506, 509);
const levelSeventhScore = rangeSCORE(510, 513);
const levelEightScore = rangeSCORE(514, 517);
const levelNinthScore = rangeSCORE(518, 528);

const ScoreValue = [levelOneScore, levelTwoScore, levelThreeScore, levelFourScore, levelFiveScore, levelSixthScore, levelSeventhScore, levelEightScore, levelNinthScore];

function showChance() {
    if(ScoreValue.includes(score)) {
        console.log(score)
    }
}
```

here is my HTML code

```
<input type="number" class="transparentBar" min="472" max="528" id="score" placeholder="SCORE">
```

for example, if I input value and click a button I want to know how to search a list of arrays

Comment: What is your `Score` variable, it's never defined?

Comment: We need all of your code - including this `rangeSCORE` function, and any other code you have not placed in your question that is necessary to solve the problem.

Comment: @JackBashford I have edited the question with the necessary components

Comment: We still do not have this `rangeSCORE` function. Please include it.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I have added the source variable

Comment: What is the desired effect/output of your code?

Comment: Also, `score` is not the same thing as `Score`.

Comment: You still have not defined `Score`

Comment: @CertainPerformance sorry I made a typo I have fixed it now

Comment: @trincot I am trying to learn how to pull the specific array where the information resides and the specific components in that array when I search them in my input value and click a button

Comment: You still need to post the `rangeSCORE` function, since that's what `ScoreValue` is created from, hard to say what `ScoreValue.includes(` might do without knowing `rangeSCORE`

Comment: @CertainPerformance my apologies again I just am having alot of typos I have edited now where the function of rangeScore is coming from

Comment: If `ScoreValue` is an array of arrays, it'll never `.includes` a *string*

Comment: @CertainPerformance then how would I go about searching a value among an array of arrays instead of making the array very long an unorganized

Comment: Now it looks like there are *two* functions - one named `rangeScore` which is never used, and one named `rangeSCORE`, does it do something different? Please post all the relevant code *verbatim* when you post the question

Comment: @CertainPerformance hello I have made the necessary adjustments sorry for my cap sensitive mistakes

Answer (score 1):

You would benefit from a different data structure. You want to map a score to a level, so the easiest would be to create an array of which the indexes represent scores and the corresponding array value represents the level.

You could create such an array like this:

```js
const scoreToLevel = [].concat(...
    [485, 489, 493, 497, 501, 505, 509, 513, 517, 528].map((end, i, ends) =>
        Array(end - (ends[i-1] || -1)).fill(i)
    )
);


// I/O handling:
const scoreInput = document.getElementById('score');
const levelOutput = document.getElementById('level');
scoreInput.addEventListener("input", function showChance() {
    levelOutput.textContent = scoreToLevel[this.value];
});
```

```html
Score: <input type="number" class="transparentBar" min="472" max="528" id="score" placeholder="SCORE"><br>
Level: <span id="level"></span>
```

Note that here the start of the ranges is not specified as that seems to always be adjacent to the end of the previous range.

Answer (score 0):

You define the rangeSCORE as  2D array. So try this and it will search for any score inside rangeSCORE.

```js
    function rangeSCORE(start, end) {
            return Array(end - start + 1).fill().map((_, idx) => start + idx)
        }




const levelOneScore = rangeSCORE(486, 489);
const levelTwoScore = rangeSCORE(490, 493);
const levelThreeScore = rangeSCORE(494, 497);
const levelFourScore = rangeSCORE(498, 501);
const levelFiveScore = rangeSCORE(502, 505);
const levelSixthScore = rangeSCORE(506, 509);
const levelSeventhScore = rangeSCORE(510, 513);
const levelEightScore = rangeSCORE(514, 517);
const levelNinthScore = rangeSCORE(518, 528);

const ScoreValue = [levelOneScore, levelTwoScore, levelThreeScore, levelFourScore, levelFiveScore, levelSixthScore, levelSeventhScore, levelEightScore, levelNinthScore];

function showChance() {
const score = document.getElementById('score').value;
   
for(var i=0;i<ScoreValue.length;i++)
{ 

for(var j=0;j<ScoreValue[i].length;j++){
 if (ScoreValue[i][j]==score){
  console.log(score);
  console.log("level",i);
}
  }
}

}
```

```html
<input type="number" class="transparentBar" min="472" max="528" id="score" placeholder="SCORE" onchange=showChance()>
```